# audioTrack play() plays only once

Tags: android

using Android's AudioTrack for the first time.
I have created a class AndroidAudioDevice. I init it with this constructor:

```
 public AndroidAudioDevice( ){  // constructor
           Log.i("Audio", "constructor");
           int minSize =AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize( SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT );        
           track = new AudioTrack( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE, 
                                                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
                                                minSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

           createSample();
           track.write( buffer, 0, buffer.length );
       };
```

(SAMPLE_RATE is set to 44100).

My main activity simply has a button, which calls

```
public void playSound(){
           track.play();
           Log.i("Audio", "playState: " + track.getPlayState());
       };

this works find BUT ONLY ONCE! If I press the button again no sound anymore.
```

BTW: Log.i displays a "3" for the playstate

Any idea why this works only once? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

State 3 is [PLAYSTATE_PLAYING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#PLAYSTATE_PLAYING). I would try either calling [stop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#stop%28%29) or [reloadStaticData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#reloadStaticData%28%29) before calling `play` the second time.

Comment: hm, interesting I had to call stop() AND reloadStaticData() before calling play() a second time. Doing so it works. Still I wonder why I have to reloadStaticData again? Anyway - Thanks Femi!

Comment: I added track.stop(); and track.reloadStaticData() before calling play and it still won't play a second time. There's no error I just hear nothing and getPlayState() is 1 and getPlaybackHeadPosition() is 0